# How to edit list item class in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm having hard time to edit my wp_nav_menu

I'm using this code to edit my ul class

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('menu_class=nav); ?>
```

I also want to edit the li class. I'm getting this

```
<li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24">
```

I want to be like this

```
<li id="menu-item-24" class="nav-links">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking **Adding Conditional Classes** to Menu Items in this url: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu. You need to use `$classes[]` array.